# Suppose that A satisfies $A^2 - 3A +2I = 0$. Find the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^2$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

knowing that A satisfies the equation $A^2 - 3A +2I = 0$ . I want to find the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^2$. I don't know where to start. Can you explain how to solve such type of questions ?

Comment: related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem

Comment: You can only find all *possible* eigenvalues of $A$ and $A^2$, but there is no way you can tell what *exactly* these eigenvalues are without additional information.

Comment: $$\text{spec}(A)\subseteq\{1,2\},\qquad \text{spec}(A^2)\subseteq\{1,4\}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. If you apply the given equation to the vector $v$, you find
$$
\begin{align}
0 &= (A^2 - 3A + 2I)v \\
&= A^2v - 3Av + 2v \\
&= A(\lambda v) - 3\lambda v + 2v \\
&= \lambda^2v - 3\lambda v + 2v \\
&= (\lambda^2 - 3\lambda + 2)v
\end{align}
$$
So what does this tell you about the quantity $(\lambda^2 - 3\lambda + 2)$?

For the second question, note that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ (If your matrix is diagonalizable, this is easy to see. It's not much worse if it isn't, using Jordan Canonical Form).