How can one find the Jordan normal form for $A$ satisfying $A^2-3A+2Id=0$?
How can one find the Jordan normal form for $A$ satisfying $A^2-3A+2Id=0$?
I have the task of finding the Jordan normal form for the operator (there is no information about the dimension of the space). I did it in the following way
$A^2-3A+2Id=0$
$\chi_A(x)=x^2-3x+2$
$(x-1)(x-2)=0$
Which means that the eigenvalues will be equal to
$\lambda_1=1$,
$\lambda_2=2$
They have multiplicity 1, and hence the Jordan normal form has the form
$J = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$
But I am not sure of the correctness of my solution, because I can't find examples of solving such problems.
If there are any mistakes here, please point them out (I will be very grateful if you help me to correct them).
And if my solution is completely wrong, can you please explain how to solve such type of questions?

You don't say that $A$ is $2\times 2$: if you mean that you should say that.


What is the dimension of the space? 2) Is the form you want for $A$, or for $A^2-3A+2I$, which is also an operator?


If all you know about a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ is that $A^2-3A+2I=0$ then there are two other possible Jordan forms: $I$ and $2I$ satisfy the condition.

@ancientmathematician In the problem there is no information about which matrix exactly, I wrote the solution for $2*2$ since I only thought of it. Also please tell me how we can find other Jordan forms which satisfy the condition

@ArturoMagidin 1)There is no information about it in the task 2)I need the form for A

Fix the problem and copy it exactly. Right now the "question" is nonsense and your "solution" is also nonsense. Because the quoted question does not tell you that $A^2-3A+2I$ equals $0$, as you apparently assumed, and what you wrote literally asks for the form of $A^2-3A+2I$, not $A$. If you can't even state the question being asked intelligibly, then of course you cannot answer it.

@ArturoMagidin done.

Put the question in the post. The title is not part of the post. You do not start reading a book by reading the spine.

You have no justification for claiming the characteristic polynomial is $x^2-3x+2$.

@ArturoMagidin I found the given characteristic polynomial in this question, I did not rewrite it. I'll fix it now https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871423/suppose-that-a-satisfies-a2-3a-2i-0-find-the-eigenvalues-of-a-and-a

Then you found a false statement, so congratulations. It is not true that if a matrix satisfies $A^2-3A+2I=0$, then its characteristic polynomial is $x^2-3x+2$. It's certainly not true if the matrix is not $2\times 2$, and it is not necessarily true even if it is $2\times 2$. Stop pinging me just to tell me false things.

@ArturoMagidin Can you please tell me how to solve this problem then? Just like I wrote in the question, I can't find any examples of solving such problems, that's why I'm stuck at this point

Here's one example. Took all of one minute to find.

If we only know that a matrix $A$ satisfies $A^2-3A+2I=0$ then all we know is that the minimal polynomial $m_A(x)$ divides $x^2-3x+2=(x-2)(x-1)$. Therefore there are four cases to consider, and we deal with them one by one.
Case(i) $m_A(x)=1$.
That would mean that $Iv=0$ for all $v$. Hence our underlying space is $0$-dimensional, and I assume you meant to exclude that case.
Case(ii) $m_A(x)=(x-2)$.
That means $A-2\cdot I=0$, so that $A=2\cdot I$ which is already in Jordan Form.
Case(iii) $m_A(x)=x-1$.
Again, $A=1\cdot I$ and is in Jordan Form.
Case(iv) $m_A(x)=(x-2)(x-1)$.
The easiest way to proceed is to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.
If $V$ is our underlying space, then
$$V=\ker (A^2-3A+2I) =\ker (A-2I)\oplus \ker (A-I)\tag{*}$$
as $x-1, x-2$ are coprime.
That means that with a change of basis $A$ is a diagonal matrix with $1$s and $2$s on the diagonal: this is its Jordan Form.
[If you don't know the application of the Chinese Remainder Theorem which gives the result $(*)$, you can prove $(*)$ for yourself in this special case. It's clear that $\ker (A-2I)$ and $\ker (A-I)$ are subspaces of $V$ which don't intersect, so $\ker (A-2I)+\ker (A-I) = \ker (A-2I)\oplus\ker (A-I)$ is a subspace of $V$. But every element $v\in V$ can be written $v=(A-I)v - (A-2I)v$, and as $(A-I)v\in\ker (A-2I)v$ and $-(A-2I)v\in\ker (A-I)v$ we get that $v\in\ker (A-2I)\oplus\ker (A-I)$ as required for $(*)$.]

@CuriousOne you are so right, thanks; sorted.

You can't conclude that $x^2 - 3x + 2$ is the characteristic polynomial - take $A = \text{Diag}(1, 1, 2)$ for a counterexample. However, it is an annihiliating polynomial - thus the minimal polynomial is either $(x-1)(x-2)$, or one of those factors.
The minimal polynomial gives us the maximal size for a Jordan block of that specific eigenvalue, and all eigenvalues are factors of the minimal polynomial.
Therefore, your matrix $A$ has a diagonal Jordan Normal form with 1s and 2s on the diagonal.
This is all we can conclude, as any such matrix satisfies your equation.
